# Multithreading with very low latencies for calls between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, pthreads

I'm starting on a new robot control software for our robotic system which has to read out values from multiple, independent sensors and control the motors accordingly.

The software will be running on an i5 PC with PREEMPT_RT Ubuntu. Each sensor device comes with an SDK which I want to run in a separate thread. As soon as they get new values from their sensors (can be up to 50 doubles at once from one sensor) they should update those values in a superior control thread. The update rate depends on the sensor, but will be as fast as 1 kHz. As soon as the "main sensor" got new values and sent them to the control thread, the thread of the main sensor should trigger the control loop in the control thread (with a non-blocking call). The control thread should then compute new values for the motors with the currently stored sensor values and transmit them to the motors. The main sensor that will trigger the control loop is also getting new data at a 1 kHz rate, so this often the control thread must be performed.

I'm unsure now how to approach this. Do you think the threads functionality from C++11 can already solve this? Or should I use something like pthreads or boost?
The main requirements are super low latency (~ 10 µs) to send data (up to 50 doubles) from one thread to another, and the ability to trigger a function (non-blocking) in another thread.

As soon as the sensor threads sent the current data to the control thread, they should continue monitoring the hardware to check for new sensor values and retrieve them. Some of the sensor threads perform extra computations and filtering on the sensor data, that's why I want them to run in extra threads, then taking advantage of the quadcore processor.

Comment: C++11 threads on Ubuntu wrap pthreads. Boost on Ubuntu also wraps pthreads. I would personally try C++11 threading and then learn how to use google benchmark to make sure everything is fast.

Comment: The CPU time is probably unimportant.  The slow part is likely to be the time reading from the sensors.  I/O can be slow.

Comment: Just run some profiler to lactate actual bottleneck. Most probably @stark is right and IO operations are slow. By the way: multi threading quite often is seen as golden hammer for performance issues, when in fact it introduces extra penalties to perform proper data synchronization.

Comment: "Low latency" has a lot of meaning.  What is the response curve of the motors to a changed signal?  If the motor takes 3 ms (which is pretty close to instant) to respond to control input, spending a bunch of time reducing the latency to 10 µs will be a waste of time.  Second, what are your power requirements?  You plugged in?  Do you mind railing a CPU (hyper thread) core?  1 kHz of 50 doubles is 50 * 8 * 1000 bytes/second, or ~400k.  Does historical data matter, or only recent data (ie, assume a lag spike: do you only care about most recent information?)

Comment: Take an introduction to realtime programming. You can never achieve a 10µs latency reliably without actual realtime support within the whole system. However, you can get pretty good results. The point of above tutorial is to make you aware of e.g. the difference between averages and guarantees, and to give you a better idea what to make of it. Until then, build a prototype and quantify (!) its performance, so you have a way to track your own progress.

Comment: Also, if you have (close to) hard real-time requirements, the SCHED_DEADLINE scheduler in Linux may be useful.